# How to check if a view is grouped?

Tags: views, theming

In a views template, I need to check if the views rows are grouped. Which property of the $view object contains this information?

---

In the example below, `$grouped = !empty($options['grouping'][0]);` seems to work. However I don't know/understand all details about the $view object and I'm not sure if this really is a solid solution. Will this work in all situations?

Currently, my `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` looks like this:

```
<?php
$grouped = !empty($options['grouping'][0]);
$heading_classes = $grouped ? ' class="group-heading"' : '';
?>

<?php if ($grouped): ?>
  <div class="views-group clearfix">
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3<?php print $heading_classes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php if ($grouped): ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips about your solution:

1- It looks right to me. I would try keep the logic separate from the template. I'd also declare my own template to avoid problems. Another style plugin, for example a custom style plugin, could use the original template.

```
HOOK_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$vars){
  if(!empty($options['grouping'])){
    $vars['heading_classes'] = $grouped ? ' class="group-heading"' : '';
    // My own template
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] = 'views_view_unformatted_group';
  }
}

/*
* Implement hook_theme
*/
HOOK_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
  return array(
    'views_view_unformatted_group' => array(
     'variables' => array(),
     'path' => 'PATH/TO/YOUR/MODULE',
     'template' => 'views_view_unformatted_group',
  ),
}
```

Template views_view_unformatted_group.tpl.php

```
<div class="views-group clearfix">
 <?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
 <h3<?php print $heading_classes; ?>><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
  <?php print $row; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

2 - The default function that manage the grouping is `render_grouping_sets()` in an style plugin object. The documentation warn about that:

> Plugins may override this method if they wish some other way of handling
>      * grouping

The unformatted list, html list, grid and table style inherit the default methods and they don't override it.

3 - If you have nested groups, Views wrap the parent group with the next function in theme.inc:

```
function theme_views_view_grouping($vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];
  $title = $vars['title'];
  $content = $vars['content'];

  $output = '<div class="view-grouping">';
  $output .= '<div class="view-grouping-header">' . $title . '</div>';
  $output .= '<div class="view-grouping-content">' . $content . '</div>' ;
  $output .= '</div>';

  return $output;
}
```